# XPath matches an element from a list using a string contant but not with the value of another element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an xslt that I am using to generate html from an XML file - working fine.  At one point I need to add some additional information from another XML file.  The two xml files share a filename (attribute in one element in the other one with the file extension and one without) which is how I want to find the information in the second xml document that corresponds with the main xml document.

The documents look like this (with a few elements removed):

Scenario_Listing.xml

```
<Scenario_Listing>
   <Scenario_List>
   <Scenario>
      <Title>
         <battle_title>Caltagirone H2H</battle_title>
      </Title>
      <filename>Caltagirone H2H</filename>
      <picture_link>scenpics/Caltagirone H2H.bmp</picture_link>
      <Map_Size>
         <map_area>0.727 Sq. km</map_area>
         <map_width>688 m</map_width>
         <map_depth>1056 m</map_depth>
      </Map_Size>
      <region>Italy</region>
   </Scenario>

   <Scenario>
      <Title>
         <battle_title>Palma di Montechiaro</battle_title>
      </Title>
      <filename>Palma di Montechiaro - AI</filename>
      <picture_link>scenpics/Palma di Montechiaro - AI.bmp</picture_link>
      <Map_Size>
         <map_area>0.067 Sq. km</map_area>
         <map_width>320 m</map_width>
         <map_depth>208 m</map_depth>
      </Map_Size>
   </Scenario>

   </Scenario_List>
</Scenario_Listing>
```

The secondary xml file looks like this:

Extra_Info.xml

```
<scenarios>
    <scenario author="information unavailable" filename="AD Flak Hunt.btt">
        <downloadurls>
            <downloadurl who="Battle Front">http://www.battlefront.com/index.php?option=com_remository&amp;Itemid=314&amp;func=fileinfo&amp;id=3036</downloadurl>
        </downloadurls>
    </scenario>
    <scenario author="information unavailable" filename="Palma di Montechiaro - AI.btt" stock="y"/>
</scenarios>
```

Inside a template I am iterating over all Scenario elements in the Scenario_List.  The variable $extraInfo contains the secondary xml document and is loaded up much earlier for use in looking up additional information.  A snippet from the template looks like this:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="Scenario_List/Scenario">
        <xsl:variable name="scenarioExtraInfo" select="$extraInfo/scenarios/scenario[@filename=concat(filename,'.btt')]"/>

        <xsl:message>filename element |<xsl:value-of select="filename" />|, concat file extension |<xsl:value-of select="concat(filename, '.btt')" />|</xsl:message>
        <xsl:message>just picking the first one |<xsl:value-of select="$extraInfo/scenarios/scenario[1]/@filename" />| look up by string |<xsl:value-of select="$extraInfo/scenarios/scenario[@filename=concat('Palma di Montechiaro - AI', '.btt')]/@filename" />| look up using the filename element |<xsl:value-of select="$extraInfo/scenarios/scenario[@filename=concat(filename,'.btt')]/@filename" />|</xsl:message>
```

When I process the template:

saxon9t -s:FortressItaly\Scenarios\Scenario_Listing.xml -xsl:scenario_campaign_listing.xsl -o:html\FortressItaly\Scenarios\index.html gameName="Fortress Italy" game=FortressItaly extrainfopath=FortressItaly/Scenarios

I see this output for the entry:

```
filename element |Palma di Montechiaro - AI|, concat file extension |Palma di Montechiaro - AI.btt|
just picking the first one |AD Flak Hunt.btt| look up by string |Palma di Montechiaro - AI.btt| look up using the filename element ||
```

I cannot figure out why when I look up based on a hard coded string 
select="$extraInfo/scenarios/scenario[**@filename=concat('Palma di Montechiaro - AI', '.btt')**]/@filename" I get the expected result but when I look up using the value of the element 
select="$extraInfo/scenarios/scenario[**@filename=concat(filename,'.btt')**]/@filename" I get nothing, even though the expression results in the same file name string.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use this expression...

```
<xsl:variable name="scenarioExtraInfo"             
              select="$extraInfo/scenarios/scenario[@filename=concat(filename,'.btt')]"/>
```

It is looking for a `filename` element that is a child of the `scenario` element in the other file. Not the `filename` element in the main file for the current `Scenario` node

Try this instead

```
<xsl:variable name="scenarioExtraInfo" 
              select="$extraInfo/scenarios/scenario[@filename=concat(current()/filename,'.btt')]"/>
```

Where `current()` will refer to the current `Scenario` node in your `xsl:for-each` statement.

Or maybe this...

```
<xsl:variable name="filename" select="filename" />
<xsl:variable name="scenarioExtraInfo" 
              select="$extraInfo/scenarios/scenario[@filename=concat($filename,'.btt')]"/>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I knew it would be something simple / obvious after seeing the solution.  It makes perfect sense of course that the XPath needs context to know what filename (or any other name means).